# How do you define styles option for Tikz `\tikz{...}`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

Usually for defining TikZ styles you could add them in square brackets after the beginning of a `tikzpicture`, something like this:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        foo/.style={shape=circle, draw}
        ]

        \node[foo] at (0,0) {label};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way to do something similar for tikz elements defined in a figure that looks like this?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikz{
        \node at (0,0) {label};
    }
\end{figure}
```

For example, the following doesn't work.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \tikz{
        [foo/.style={shape=circle, draw}]
        \node[foo] at (0,0) {label};
    }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It makes no difference if your TikZ is in a figure or not. Also `\tikz{...}` is the same as `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`. What is your goal? Do you want a `style` applied to all your `\node`s in all of your document?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, and you want a `style` applied, but only if the `\node` is inside a figure!?

Comment: You can use `\tikz[foo/.style={shape=circle, draw}]{...}` but as @hpekristiansen said this is the same as the other one.

Comment: It's about defining a style inside `\tikz{...}` like you would in `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` with square brackets. Adding square brackets in `\tikz{...}` doesn't compile properly. And any styles defined there used inside the `tikz`

Comment: Huh, that works, idk why I was messing around and didn't get to work it like that. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it @TikZling

Comment: You might also look at `\tikzset{foo/.style={...}}` which can be done globally (outside a tikzpicture environment).